# Empathy - Linux Mint 17.1 Cinnamon

Tags: linux, empathy

I've been a linux mint user for 2 days now and I've been trying to use Empathy. I've installed the software from software manager without any problem. but when I try to add an account, **it is showing me no choice to choose**.
Here is a screenshot of the problem:
[image: Empathy not allowing me to choose the kind of chat account]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install at least one of the `account-plugin-*` package; for example:

```
account-plugin-aim
account-plugin-evernote
account-plugin-facebook
account-plugin-fitbit
account-plugin-flickr
account-plugin-foursquare
account-plugin-gadugadu
account-plugin-google
account-plugin-groupwise
account-plugin-icons
account-plugin-icq
account-plugin-identica
account-plugin-instagram
account-plugin-irc
account-plugin-jabber
account-plugin-linkedin
account-plugin-mxit
account-plugin-myspace
account-plugin-salut
account-plugin-sametime
account-plugin-sina
account-plugin-sip
account-plugin-sohu
account-plugin-tools
account-plugin-twitter
account-plugin-ubuntuone
account-plugin-windows-live
account-plugin-yahoo
account-plugin-yahoojp
account-plugin-zephyr
```

Comment: How do i do that?

Comment: Nevermind i got it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, on arch linux, I had to run:

`yaourt -S telepathy-gabble`

And I saw the account types.